ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 3), gps time to UTC
Trying to convert GPS times to a date and time of day in UTC. Inputs are space separated stream of x y seconds and output is a stream of x y z date time
This was designed to work with lidar data and the input may have come from a command like 'las2txt -parse xyt ...'.
import datetime
import fileinput

#number of seconds between the start of unix time (Jan 1, 1970) and gps time (Jan 6, 1980)
offset = 315964800


def countleaps(gpsTime):
  """Count number of leap seconds that have passed."""

  # a tuple of the gps times where leap seconds were added
  leaps = (
    46828800, 78364801, 109900802, 173059203, 252028804,
    315187205, 346723206, 393984007, 425520008, 457056009,
    504489610, 551750411, 599184012, 820108813, 914803214, 
    1025136015
    )

  nleaps = 0
  for leap in leaps:  
    if gpsTime >= leap:
       nleaps += 1
  
  return nleaps

if __name__ == '__main__':
  for line in fileinput.input(r'E:\LiDAR\Staging\GW_Workspace\Beaverhead_Reports\BH_0001.txt'):
    xvalue, yvalue, zvalue, timevalue=line.split(' ')[:4]
    gpstime=float(timevalue)
    gpstime += 1e9; # unadjusted GPS time
    unixtime = gpstime + offset - countleaps(gpstime);
    datetimestr = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(unixtime).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    
    print xvalue, yvalue, zvalue, datetimestr

Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\cwc051\PycharmProjects\sandbox\.venv\Sanbox_script.py", line 29, in <module>
    xvalue, yvalue, zvalue, timevalue=line.split(' ') [:4]
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 3)


How could the previous line possibly work with this path written directly without quotes?

It's quoted in my code, not sure why it's not on here.

Ok.. so... what about editing your question so the code you posted is the code you say you have?

The problem is very obviously in the contents of line.  What is the value when you get the error?

Your problem is here: timevalue=line.split(' ')[:4]
You're telling python "Assign values to these four variables using the first four elements in the array resulting from the split operation", but based on the contents of the error you're receiving, at least one line only has two spaces in it, so the array has only three elements, so there is no fourth element to assign to the timevalue variable.

@Barmar I did. "At lease one line only has two spaces in it" means there's a line in the file with only two spaces in it that's causing the problem. How to fix it depends entirely on the shape of the data in the file and how the line(s) in question should be treated by the application, neither of which is available in the question.

This is helpful. It seems like I will have to either skip any data with only two spaces?  I am very new to coding but it seems like this would be the most reasonable way to go about this.

Sorry for the slow reply... Yes, you could skip lines that have an unanticipated number of spaces, but it depends. You may, for example, want to raise an exception (or at least log an error) if that's an unexpected condition in the file(s) you're analyzing, so that you don't end up processing bad data or getting unexpected behavior in your application that has more to do with the data than the code.

If a line doesn't have at least 4 fields, you can't assign them to 4 variables. You need to check for that and take appropriate action:
fields = line.split(' ')
if len(fields) >= 4:
    xvalue, yvalue, zvalue, timevalue=fields[:4]
else:
    # assign variables some other way

or you could simply skip those lines:
if len(fields) < 4:
    continue

